# Attempt of a question dealing with the Intermediate Value Theorem

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, continuity

I'm new to proofs, and I recently got introduced to the Intermediate Value Theorem and decided to practice some questions. So, I was wondering if I got the following question right and if I'm even on the right track.

> The question is:

Assume that $f$ and $g$ are continous on the interval $[a,b]$ and $g(a) ≤ f(x) ≤ g(b)$ for all $x∈[0,1]$. Show there exists some $c\in[a,b]$ such that $f(c) = g(c)$.

> My attempt:

**Case 1.** If $f(a)=g(a)$, we're done since there's nothing to prove.
**Case 2.** If $f(b)=g(b)$, we're also done.

**Case 3.** If $f(a)\neq g(a)$ and $f(b)\neq g(b)$. Then, suppose the function $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$. 
Now, if $f(a)\neq g(a)$, then $f(a) > g(a)$. This implies 
$h(a) = f(a) - g(a)$
⇔$h(a) > f(a)$.

Similiariy,
if $f(b)\neq g(b)$, then $f(b) < g(b)$. This implies 
$h(b) = f(b) - g(b)$
⇔$h(b) < f(b)$.
 So, by the I.V.T theorem, there exists a $c∈(a,b)$ so that $h(c) = 0$

⇔$f(c) - g(c) = 0$

⇔$f(c) = g(c)$ as needed.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: In Case 3, $h(a)>0$ and $h(b)<0$ on your 2nd and 3rd paragraph. I believe it's a typo, but other than that, I don't see anything wrong in the proof!

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not quite sure I understand. Isn't it supposed to be $h(a)>f(a)$ and $h(b)<f(b)$ since we want to show that there exists some $c∈(a,b)$ such that $f(c)=g(c)$?

Comment: Take the second example, if you have $f(b)<g(b)$, then $h(b)  = f(b)-g(b)<0$

Comment: Do you recall what the intermediate value theorem states?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Case 3, $h(a)>0$ and $h(b)<0$ on your 2nd and 3rd paragraph. I believe it's a typo. Other than that, I don't see anything wrong in the proof!

Perhaps it's simpler to combine Case 1 and Case 2.

Something along the lines of "If they are equal at the end points, there's nothing to proof."

Suppose not, then necessarily $f(a)>g(a)$ and $f(b)<g(b)$. Define a function $h=f-g$ and we have $h(a)>0$ and $h(b)<0$.

Then since $h$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $h(a)<0<h(b)$ [Notice how 0 is the 'intermediate value'], we have $h(c)=0$ for some $c\in(a,b)$ by the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

In your solution you compared $h$ and $f$, but this does not give the desired result. Instead, you should check for the sign of $h$: 
For $f(a) > g(a)$, we have
$$f(a) - g(a) > 0$$
$$h(a) > 0$$
And for $f(b) < g(b)$, we have
$$f(b) - g(b) < 0$$
$$h(b) < 0$$
Now, since $f$ and $g$ are continuous on $[a,b]$, $h$ is continuous in the same interval.
Therefore we can use the IVT to conclude that there exists some $c \in [a,b]$ such that $h(c) = 0$, or
$$f(c) = g(c)$$
The proof is complete.